# How to compile "directly"(with an icon) a PsTricks code with WinEdt?

Tags: pstricks, winedt

(Win8 + Winedt 10.2 + MikTeX 2.9.6515)

I usually use Winedt with PDFLaTeX or PDFTeXify, with this icon
[image]

If I want to compile a PsTricks code, I need to:
1.- compile with LATEX (L icon), then
2.- DVI2PS (icon), then
3.- PS2PDF (icon), and finally I obtain the PDF file.
[image]

BUT...
If I want to use PDFLaTeX directly with a PSTRicks code I obtain the error:
"! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks_Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.13 ...{\circlenode{IL}{\textcolor{red}{I like}}}"

**The question is:**
*How could I do that proccess directly? or How to use PsTricks code using PDFLaTeX(PDFTeXify or other similar)?. In this example to obtain the final result:*
[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

 \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(12,6) %\malla

 \rput(4.5,3){\circlenode{IL}{\textcolor{red}{I like}}}
 \rput(8.5,3.5){\circlenode{L}{\textcolor{blue}{\LaTeX}}}
 \rput(6.5,-0.5){\circlenode{G}{\textcolor{blue}{\footnotesize{Galicia(Spain)}}}}


 \ncarc[arcangle=22]{->}{IL}{L}
 \nbput*{\small Yes}   % This line show error on compiling.

 \ncarc[arcangle=22]{->}{L}{IL}
 \ncput*{\small No}   % This l

 \ncarc[arcangle=8]{->}{L}{G}
 \ncarc[arcangle=-22,linewidth=0.05,linecolor=red]{->}{G}{L}

 \ncarc[arcangle=-22,linewidth=0.05,linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]{->}{IL}{G}

 \rput(2,0){This is a test.}
\rput(8,-2){Esto é unha proba.}


 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a winedt macro package called latexify, http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/LaTeXify.html that offers more shortcuts, e.g. `LaTeXify2PDF (runs Biber and TeXify+dvips+ps2pdf with LaTeX engine)`. Or you could use arara or latexmk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xelatex`  instead of `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. It needs only some changes:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
%
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
[...]
```

UTF-8 is the default of `xelatex`

Comment: is this valid for tikz pictures?… in general

Comment: Yes, there is no difference